# GlobIterator no file found php 5.3.7+ error

Tags: php

i try to do

```
<?php
$i = new \GlobIterator('/test/file*.gz');
echo $i->count();
```

With file*.gz may not exist. And when no file found i got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'The parent constructor was not called: the object is in an invalid state ' in /in/qHHhR:3
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /in/qHHhR(3): SplFileInfo->_bad_state_ex()

As you can see here http://3v4l.org/qHHhR, it's not working only 5.3.7+

PHP bug or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, as CBroe say it's a php bug.

A solution (found on https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55701) is to do like this:

```
// Next works as expected: no xml files found = no output
foreach (new GlobIterator($path_to_files . '/*.xml') as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
}

$it = new GlobIterator($path_to_files . '/*.xml');
// Expected result: count = 0
// Instead next line will crash php if no xml files are found
if ($it->count()) {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method that looks cleaner to me:

```
try {
  $count = $i->count();
} catch ( \LogicException $e) {
  $count = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.iterator-to-array.php)

```
count(iterator_to_array($i))
// return 0
```